# Datos logicos true o false

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo solicitar un dato lógico como (True o Flase) y después usarlo en un ejercicio?

```
p = input("Por favor ingrese True o False para p")
```

Comment: Luego comparas `if p == 'True':`

Comment: si el ejercicio es asi : print(r | (p | (not q) | (not r) & False )) (pero me dicen, dele valores de verdadero o falso a p,q,r) como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: `p=True`, por ejemplo, si debes asignar esos valores por programa. Si se los pides al usuario puedes hacer `p = (input("True o False? ").lower() == "true")`

Comment: gracias pero ejemplo, yo quiero correr el programa y que al correrlo me pida que de le valor verdadero o falso y los digite y el sistema despues realice el ejercicio y me de la respuesta 
p = bool(input("Por favor introduce True o False para p "))
q = bool(input("Por favor introduce True o False para q "))
r = bool(input("Por favor introduce True o False para r ")) 
si lo hago asi el resultado siempre me dara verdadero

Comment: `input()` te devuelve una cadena. Tratar de hacer `bool()` sobre la cadena devuelta te va a dar siempre `True`, porque el valor booleano de una cadena es True salvo cuando la cadena está vacía. Por eso yo te sugería que asignaras el booleano que resulta **de comparar** la cadena introducida con la cadena `"true"`. Eso es lo que hacía mi sugerencia: `p = (input("Valor para p? ").lower() == "true")`. Esto dejará el booleano `True` en `p` si el usuario escribe "True", o `False` si escribe cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: Gracias ahora si me funciono tiene razón, si escribo sobre la opción me da verdadero, y si la dejo vacía me da falso ... mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

puedes aplicar el siguiente código "p":

```
  opcion:int = -1
  p:bool = False

  while (opcion == -1):
     print("1. [ True ] - 2.[ False ]")
     opcion = input("Favor digirar el valor de p")
  
     if opcion == 1:
       p = True
     else if opcion == 2:
       p = False
     else:
       print("Opcion incorrecta !!")
       opcion = -1
```

Comment: de ante mano gracias, pero no me sirve por que el ejercicio es sobre logicos y abria que darle el valor de True o False sin numero y para este ejercicio 

print(r | (p | (not q) | (not r) & False ))

la respuesta seria falso

Comment: normalmente me dan los datos y el programa corre y me da la respuesta ejemplo:


w = 6
y = 3
x = 2
z = -4
p = False
q = True
r = False

# Ejercicio 1
print(x + z * y / w)
# Ejercicio 2
print(14 % w % y)        
# Ejercicio 3
print(r | (p | (not q) | (not r) & False ))
# Ejercicio 4
print((x + z) * y / w)
# Ejercicio 5
print(y - abs(z) * w)

Comment: yo necesito lo contrario que el sistema me lo pida y haga los ejercicios ejemplo:
w = int(input("Por favor introduce un valor para w "))
y = int(input("Por favor introduce un valor para y "))
x = int(input("Por favor introduce un valor para x "))
z = int(input("Por favor introduce un valor para z "))
p = bool(input("Por favor introduce True o False para p "))
q = bool(input("Por favor introduce True o False para q "))
r = bool(input("Por favor introduce True o False para r "))
print(x + z * y / w)
print(14 % w % y)
print(r | (p | (not q) | (not r) & False ))

Comment: La variable `opcion` tienes que compararla como string.

Comment: @user212095. Mejor edita tu pregunta para incluir está información adicional.